# Specific number of input elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words and my input is one of the words in the first half of the list (in this case, this list is a german song). Now I take the lenght of this word and jump this the length of this word in list, f.e. first word in the list is "Es" and the length is 2. Now we count from "Es" 2 times and we land by word "zwei". I should go through this list and check if the word appears again in the second half of the list.

The program works, but the problem is about the input. It takes one word and sees if the theorie works.
This is the song list: "hin" is the last word of the first half

```
song = [
    "Es", "gingen", "zwei", "Parallelen",
    "ins", "Endlose", "hinaus",
    "zwei", "kerzengerade", "Seelen",
    "und", "aus", "solidem", "Haus", 

    "Sie", "wollten", "sich", "nicht", "schneiden", 
    "bis", "an", "ihr", "seliges", "Grab", 
    "Das", "war", "nun", "einmal", "der", "beiden", 
    "geheimer", "Stolz", "und", "Stab", 

    "Doch", "als", "sie", "zehn", "Lichtjahre", 
    "gewandert", "neben", "sich", "hin", #End of the first half of the song
    "da", "wards", "dem", "einsamen", "Paare", 
    "nicht", "irdisch", "mehr", "zu", "Sinn", 

    "Warn", "sie", "noch", "Parallelen",
    "Sie", "wusstens", "selber", "nicht", 
    "sie", "flossen", "nur", "wie", "zwei", "Seelen",
    "zusammen", "durch", "ewiges", "Licht", 

    "Das", "ewige", "Licht", "durchdrang", "sie",
    "da", "wurden", "sie" "eins", "in", "ihm", 
    "die", "Ewigkeit", "verschlang", "sie",
    "als", "wie", "zwei", "Seraphim"]
```

I want my input to be all the words of the first half of the list (song in this case), not just one word. So it just prints out the result (result is a list in this case) for each word in every line.

[image: This is how the output now looks]

And I want it to immediatly print every result for each word in the first half and if the theorie works. This would be than the ouput:

Theorie works/doesn't

Result1

Theorie works/doesn't

Result2

Theorie works/doesn't

Result3

And so on...

Here is the code:

```
with open('C:/Users/xy/Desktop/BWINF/parallelen.txt', 'r') as f:

song = f.read()

noneed = "–?,.;:"
for char in noneed:
    song = song.replace(char, "")
song = song.split()

def Parallelen(listSong):

originalWord = input("Enter a word: ")
originalWordSaved = originalWord
theorie_list = [] # The list for found words
index = song.index(originalWord) # Get the index of the first instance of "word"
indexOriginal = song.index(originalWordSaved)
wordCount = song.count(originalWord)

while True:
    if indexOriginal > 42:
        print("Word is in the second half")
        break
    if wordCount <= 1:
        print("Word appears only 1 time and therefore can't appear one more time")
        print("Theorie doesn't work")
        break  
    try:
        theorie_list.append(listSong[index])
        theorie_list.append(len(listSong[index]))
        index += len(listSong[index]) 
        if listSong[index] == originalWordSaved:
            theorie_list.append(listSong[index])
            theorie_list.append(len(listSong[index]))
            print("Theorie works")
            break
    except:
        print("Theorie doesn't work") 
        break

return theorie_list

print(Parallelen(song))
```

Comment: You need to make a [mre] and [edit] it into the post. See also [ask] for more pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of the function that processes each word in the first part of the list.  The question states that the program works, so the main logic has not been changed.

These are the changes that have been made:

- remove the `input` statement
- add a `for` loop over the first part of the list
- print the word being processed (for debugging and readability, may be removed)
- remove redundant `originalWordSaved` and `originalIndex` variables
- move filtering logic (the word is in the second half of the list, or appears less than twice) out of the `while` loop as it only need to run once per word
- move code than cannot cause an `IndexError` out of the try/except block
- specifically trap `IndexError`, because that's the only error that the code can raise: bare `except` statements should be avoided
- print the list rather than returning it

```
def Parallelen(listSong):

    # Magic number: length of list is 89
    halfway = 42

    for originalWord in listSong[: halfway + 1]:
        print("\nProcessing {!r}".format(originalWord))
        theorie_list = []  # The list for found words
        index = song.index(originalWord)
        # Get the index of the first instance of "word"
        index = song.index(originalWord)
        if index > halfway:
            print("Word is in the second half")
            continue
        wordCount = song.count(originalWord)
        # The word must appear at least once
        if wordCount == 1:
            print("Word appears only 1 time and therefore can't appear one more time")
            print("Theorie doesn't work")
            continue

        while True:
            theorie_list.append(listSong[index])
            theorie_list.append(len(listSong[index]))
            index += len(listSong[index])
            try:
                if listSong[index] == originalWord:
                    theorie_list.append(listSong[index])
                    theorie_list.append(len(listSong[index]))
                    print("Theorie works")
                    break
            except IndexError:
                print("Theorie doesn't work")
                break
        print(theorie_list)

    return


Parallelen(listSong)
```